# By using Tkinter : Convert the Entry to drop down menu to choose from:

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter and would like to convert the first three `tk.Entry()` from Entry to drop down menu that enables the user to choose the percent (0.01%, 0.02%, ...etc)

```
'''This simple App calculates a (component grade) for student. The way it works like the following:
the students enter the Value of school, Qiyas, and Comprehensive (in percent out of 100%), Then
the students enter the school, Qiyas, and Comprehensive grades also (in percent out of 100%), 
the calculation of the component grade like this:
((school grade*school value)+(Qiyas*Qiyas value)+(Comprehensive grade*(Comprehensive value)))
'''

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import datetime
import tkinter as tk



window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("350x400")
window.title("Calculate the final grade")

#I would like to convert the following tk.Entry() to DropDown Menu
school_value_entry= tk.Label(text="Enter the Value of school in % (ex. 0.50)")
school_value_entry.grid(column = 0, row=1)
school_value_entry=tk.Entry()
school_value_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=1)

Qiyas_value_entry= tk.Label(text="Enter the Value of Qiyas in % (ex. 0.25)")
Qiyas_value_entry.grid(column = 0, row=2)
Qiyas_value_entry=tk.Entry()
Qiyas_value_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=2)


Comprehensive_value_entry= tk.Label(text="Enter the Value of Comprehensive in %(ex. 0.30)")
Comprehensive_value_entry.grid(column = 0, row=3)
Comprehensive_value_entry=tk.Entry()
Comprehensive_value_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=3)


school= tk.Label(text="High School Grade")
school.grid(column = 0, row=4)
school_entry=tk.Entry()
school_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=4)

Qiyas= tk.Label(text="Qiyas Grade")
Qiyas.grid(column = 0, row=5)
Qiyas_entry=tk.Entry()
Qiyas_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=5)

Comprehensive= tk.Label(text="Comprehensive Grade ")
Comprehensive.grid(column = 0, row=6)
Comprehensive_entry=tk.Entry()
Comprehensive_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=6)

#Calculating the grade& get the value from the user

def calculate_grade():
    print(school_entry.get())
    print(Qiyas_entry.get())
    print(Comprehensive_entry.get())

    Mohammed = person('Your Component Grade is:', float(school_entry.get()),
                                                float(Qiyas_entry.get()),
                                                float(Comprehensive_entry.get()),
                                                float(school_value_entry.get()),
                                                float(Qiyas_value_entry.get()),
                                                float(Comprehensive_entry.get()))

    text_answer= tk.Text(master = window, height= 20, width= 30)
    text_answer.grid(column= 2, row= 7)
    answer_text= "{} {} ".format(Mohammed.name,"%.2f" % Mohammed.grade())
    text_answer.insert(tk.END, answer_text)


claculate_butten= tk.Button(text="Calculate Grade", command= calculate_grade)
claculate_butten.grid(column = 2, row=7)


class person:

    def __init__(self, name, a, f, g, x, y, z):
        self.name= name
        self.a= school_value_entry
        self.y= Qiyas_value_entry
        self.z= Comprehensive_value_entry
        self.x= school
        self.f= Qiyas
        self.g= Comprehensive


    def grade(self):

        a= school_value_entry.get()
        f= Qiyas_value_entry.get()
        g= Comprehensive_value_entry.get()
        x= school_entry.get()
        y= Qiyas_entry.get()
        z= Comprehensive_entry.get()

        ''' the calculation of the component grade works like this:
((school grade*school value)+(Qiyas*Qiyas value)+(Comprehensive grade*(Comprehensive value))) '''

        grade  = (float(school_entry.get())*float(school_value_entry.get()))+(float(Qiyas_entry.get())*float(Qiyas_value_entry.get()))+(float(Comprehensive_entry.get())*float(Comprehensive_value_entry.get()))
        return grade

image = Image.open('/Users/macbookpro/Downloads/logo.jpg')
image.thumbnail((300, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo= ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label_image= tk.Label(image = photo)
label_image.grid(column=2 , row=0)
#input("Press enter to exit ;)")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Youv'e told us what you want (twice!) but you haven't asked a question. What do you need help with? Also, please remove all code that is not necessary for the question. See How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I am new at programming and at stack over flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well looking at your code there are several issues. The class `person` seams pointless as everything there can be done in a function. You assign variables but then you use the `.get()` method again instead of using the variables your created. So some stuff in your code is pointless.

That being said I have added some drop down menu boxes in the places of the first 3 entry boxes. The way I set it up may not be perfect but it is a start and you should be able improve on the code to meet you needs.

First I created a dictionary that we will use with the drop down boxes to provide the values of each percentage and I created some variables that we will be using later.

```
drop_choice = {}
s1 = "0.01"
q1 = "0.01"
c1 = "0.01"
```

Second I created a few functions that will be used to update s1, q1 and c1 each time their respective drop downs change.

```
def callback1(value):
    global s1
    s1 = value

def callback2(value):
    global q1
    q1 = value

def callback3(value):
    global c1
    c1 = value
```

Third I created a function that adds all the values to our drop_choice dictionary.

I did not know exactly all the values you wanted so I created 0.01-1.00.

```
def setup_percentage():
    new_percent = 0.00
    for i in range(100):
        new_percent += 0.01
        new_value = float('{0:.2f}'.format(new_percent))
        drop_choice[str(new_value)] = new_value

setup_percentage()
```

Forth I created the `StringVar()`'s for each of the drop down menus.

```
school_value_entry_variable = tk.StringVar()
Qiyas_value_entry_variable = tk.StringVar()
Comprehensive_value_entry_variable = tk.StringVar()
```

Last major change is creating the drop down menus.

```
option1 = tk.OptionMenu(window, school_value_entry_variable, *drop_choice, command = callback1)
school_value_entry_variable.set('0.01')
option1.grid(column = 2 , row=1)
```

After that I changed up some of the formulas to use the s1, q1 and c1 variables I first created.

With all this info you should be able to get a better understanding of how to set up these drop down menus.

Below is a copy paste version of your code with the added drop downs:

I left the code in where you had your first 3 entry widgets. I just commented them out and added the drop down menus.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry()
window.title("Calculate the final grade")

s1 = "0.01"
q1 = "0.01"
c1 = "0.01"

def callback1(value):
    global s1
    s1 = value

def callback2(value):
    global q1
    q1 = value

def callback3(value):
    global c1
    c1 = value

drop_choice = {}
school_value_entry_variable = tk.StringVar()
Qiyas_value_entry_variable = tk.StringVar()
Comprehensive_value_entry_variable = tk.StringVar()

def setup_percentage():
    new_percent = 0.00
    for i in range(100):
        new_percent += 0.01
        new_value = float('{0:.2f}'.format(new_percent))
        drop_choice[str(new_value)] = new_value

setup_percentage()
print(drop_choice)

#I would like to convert the following tk.Entry() to DropDown Menu
school_value_entry= tk.Label(window, text="Enter the Value of school in % (ex. 0.50)")
school_value_entry.grid(column = 0, row=1)
# school_value_entry=tk.Entry()
# school_value_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=1)
option1 = tk.OptionMenu(window, school_value_entry_variable, *drop_choice, command = callback1)
school_value_entry_variable.set('0.01')
option1.grid(column = 2 , row=1)

Qiyas_value_entry= tk.Label(window, text="Enter the Value of Qiyas in % (ex. 0.25)")
Qiyas_value_entry.grid(column = 0, row=2)
# Qiyas_value_entry=tk.Entry()
# Qiyas_value_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=2)
option2 = tk.OptionMenu(window, Qiyas_value_entry_variable, *drop_choice, command = callback2)
Qiyas_value_entry_variable.set('0.01')
option2.grid(column = 2 , row=2)

Comprehensive_value_entry= tk.Label(window, text="Enter the Value of Comprehensive in %(ex. 0.30)")
Comprehensive_value_entry.grid(column = 0, row=3)
# Comprehensive_value_entry=tk.Entry()
# Comprehensive_value_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=3)
option3 = tk.OptionMenu(window, Comprehensive_value_entry_variable, *drop_choice, command = callback3)
Comprehensive_value_entry_variable.set('0.01')
option3.grid(column = 2 , row=3)

school= tk.Label(text="High School Grade")
school.grid(column = 0, row=4)
school_entry=tk.Entry(window)
school_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=4)

Qiyas= tk.Label(text="Qiyas Grade")
Qiyas.grid(column = 0, row=5)
Qiyas_entry=tk.Entry(window)
Qiyas_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=5)

Comprehensive= tk.Label(text="Comprehensive Grade ")
Comprehensive.grid(column = 0, row=6)
Comprehensive_entry=tk.Entry(window)
Comprehensive_entry.grid(column = 2 , row=6)

#Calculating the grade& get the value from the user

def calculate_grade():
    Mohammed = person('Your Component Grade is:', float(school_entry.get()),
                                                float(Qiyas_entry.get()),
                                                float(Comprehensive_entry.get()),
                                                float(s1),
                                                float(q1),
                                                float(c1))

    text_answer= tk.Text(master = window, height= 20, width= 30)
    text_answer.grid(column= 2, row= 8)
    answer_text= "{} {} ".format(Mohammed.name,"%.2f" % Mohammed.grade())
    text_answer.insert(tk.END, answer_text)


claculate_butten= tk.Button(text="Calculate Grade", command= calculate_grade)
claculate_butten.grid(column = 2, row=7)

class person:

    def __init__(self, name, a, f, g, x, y, z):
        self.name= name
        self.a= school_value_entry
        self.y= Qiyas_value_entry
        self.z= Comprehensive_value_entry
        self.x= school
        self.f= Qiyas
        self.g= Comprehensive

    def grade(self):
        grade  = float(school_entry.get()) * float(s1) + float(Qiyas_entry.get()) * float(q1) + float(Comprehensive_entry.get()) * float(c1)
        return grade

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thaaanx Sierra so much. I know my code includes a lot of issues, the reason is that this is my first app in the programming world. It works perfectly and I learned a lot.

Comment: Glad to help. Just a note but try to learn the OOP class way of python. This way you can avoid the use of global variables. They are often not the best choice when programming.